# How to use custom Cloud Builders with images from Google Artifact Repository

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build, cloudbuild.yaml, google-artifact-registry

How do I use a custom builder image in Cloud Build which is stored in a repository in Artifact Registry (instead of Container Registry?)

I have set up a pipeline in Cloud Build where some python code is executed using official python images. As I want to cache my python dependencies, I wanted to create a custom Cloud Builder as shown in the official documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/configuring-builds/use-community-and-custom-builders#creating_a_custom_builder).

GCP clearly indicates to switch to Artifact Registry as Container Registry will be replaced by the former. Consequently, I have pushed my docker image to Artifact Registry. I also gave my Cloud Builder Service Account the reader permissions to Artifact Registry.

Using the image in a Cloud Build step like this

```html
steps:
  - name: 'europe-west3-docker.pkg.dev/xxxx/yyyy:latest'
    id: install_dependencies
    entrypoint: pip
    args: ["install", "-r", "requirements.txt", "--user"]
```

throws the following error

> Step #0 - "install_dependencies": Pulling image: europe-west3-docker.pkg.dev/xxxx/yyyy:latest
> Step #0 - "install_dependencies": Error response from daemon: manifest for europe-west3-docker.pkg.dev/xxxx/yyyy:latest not found: manifest unknown: Requested entity was not found.

"xxxx" is the repository name and "yyyy" the name of my image. The tag "latest" exists.
I can pull the image locally and access the repository.

I could not find any documentation on how to integrate these images from Artifact Registry. There is only [this official guide](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/configure-cloud-build#docker), where the image is built using the Docker image from Container Registry – however this should not be future proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need to add your Project ID to your image name.
You can use the "$PROJECT_ID" Cloud Build default substitution variable.
So your updated image name would look something like this:

```
steps:
  - name: 'europe-west3-docker.pkg.dev/$PROJECT_ID/xxxx/yyyy:latest'
```

For more details about substituting variable values in Cloud Build see:

https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/configuring-builds/substitute-variable-values